# Completely fake URL with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, amazon-cloudfront

I am serving static content with Amazon CloudFront and am using my servers as the origin.

Since CF does not respect ? query strings, I can't easily force CF to use new versions of .png files. I also need fast invalidation and do not want to pay for invalidation requests.

So I want to create a completely fake directory with .htaccess to force versioning for my images.

For instance, I want:

domain.com/static/0.12/images/background.png

going to

domain.com/static/images/background.png

Where 0.12 is my APP version, which will be automatically changed through my deployment script.

What would be the .htaccess rule for this?

Answer (score 1):

If you actually want the URL

> domain.com/static/0.12/images/background.png

to be internally redirected to

> domain.com/static/images/background.png

Add the following to the .htaccess file in the root of your site.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^static/0\.12/images/(.+)$ static/images/$1 [L,NC]
```

If the APP version varies then use

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^static/[\.0-9]+/images/(.+)$ static/images/$1 [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

To force all requests from a URL like

```
example.com/static/images/background.png
```

to rewrite to internal URLs like

```
example.com/static/0.12/images/background.png
```

Use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^static/images/(.*)$ static/0.12/images/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I think Markus wants it the other way around.