# Create a cased redirection for small cased file in Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, batch-rename

Here is the situation:

I have a static website host on Amazon S3. All files in it are small letters, for example: `file.html`

I am looking for a **script/program/tool** to find all small letter files in a S3 site and create several cased 301 redirection.

E.g. Create `File.html` and `FILE.html` two files and use the new 301 redirect feature to redirect the requests with capital letters to small letters real file.

Please advice

Comment: Because S3 is case sensitive system, so I have to look for this otherwise my site got too many 404 errors. With too many files and constantly have more so simply cannot do it manully. If you have other solution to let S3 ignore case or become case insensitive, please advice too.

Comment: is this controlling access from your site, or via a direct link (eg user typing in the URL)? If it's on your site could you fake an htaccess rewrite rule (eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003486/completely-fake-url-with-htaccess) to convert the request to lowercase before calling the S3 content?

Comment: Hi @Offbeatmammal, I directly host website on S3 with the new website feature, so I am not using cloudfront. I tried search if S3 support htaccess but no luck

Comment: it looks like no htaccess (though there were forum comments saying they're considering it) but this might help you out (rather than writing a whole bunch of files) - https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=1658

Comment: it's probably overkill but one way would be to point everything to a "real" apache webserver that basically just serves an .htaccess file to rewrite everything to lowercase filenames. S3 would be even more awesome if it had .htaccess support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've hacked together a script which does what you want. It's not well rounded by all means but should do the trick. I've put it up on GitHub at https://github.com/mikewirth/s3-caseredirect.

Usage:
`python makeredirects.py access_code secret bucketname key_for_your_file`

I've tried a version which uses the Redirection Rules feature, but that didn't work because there is a limit of around 20 rules. This script will therefore create LOTS of empty keys.

---

For completeness and because it's so small here's the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""
This script takes a file on S3 and creates a redirect from every possible
permutation of case to the original file.

Author: Michael Wirth (https://github.com/mikewirth/s3-caseredirect/)
"""

import sys
import os.path
import argparse

try:
    import boto.s3.connection

except:
    print "boto library (http://code.google.com/p/boto/) for aws needs to be installed"
    sys.exit(1)

filenames = None


def make_case_insensitive(bucket, access, secret, key):
    """ Get filename permutations """
    global filenames
    filenames = []
    filename = os.path.basename(key)
    path = os.path.dirname(key)

    filename_permutations(filename)

    connection = boto.s3.connection.S3Connection(access, secret, True)
    b = connection.get_bucket(bucket)

    for fname in filenames:
        if fname == filename:
            continue

        k = b.new_key(os.path.join(path, fname))
        k.set_redirect(key)


def filename_permutations(filename, pos=0):
    if len(filename) == pos:
        filenames.append(filename)
    else:
        upper = filename[:pos] + filename[pos:pos+1].upper() + filename[pos+1:]
        lower = filename[:pos] + filename[pos:pos+1].lower() + filename[pos+1:]

        if upper != lower:
            filename_permutations(upper, pos+1)
            filename_permutations(lower, pos+1)
        else:
            filename_permutations(filename, pos+1)


def main():
    """ CLI """
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument("access", help="AWS credentials: access code")
    parser.add_argument("secret", help="AWS credentials: secret")
    parser.add_argument("bucket", help="Name of Amazon S3 bucket")
    parser.add_argument("key", help="Name of the key to make available case-insensitively. (Starts with a slash.)")

    args = parser.parse_args()

    make_case_insensitive(args.bucket, args.access, args.secret, args.key)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks for your script. Will try, and I would love to see you refine it more.